Sci-fi TV series in a 60s setting about a secret goverment agency & aliens
I am setting my hopes of finding the name of a television series I saw as a kid.
I can´t remember when I saw it exactly, but it was sometime in the 1990s. On swedish Television. But it was imported from the US.
Plot (as far I can remember):
It´s about a young agent that is recruited to a secret government agency that deals with alien threats. It´s called something with "Majestic" in the series. Can´t remember exactly.
This young agent discovers an alien invasion in the making, in that they are taking over peoples bodies, kinda like in the movie "Puppet Masters". 
This agent tries to battle the aliens resistance group that has a hidden agenda.
During the series this agent has to deal with personal problems in that the aliens takes his girlfriend\wife and infect her. And the agent is desperate to get her back from the alien leader.
This government agency also has an underground facility in which the series takes place from time to time. Where they interrogate aliens and also has research.
The agent also discovers that there is a way to "expel" the aliens from an infected human with a special method.
--- END PLOT ---
The actors are fairly known, though I can´t right now remember any names. I can however via images identify the actors.
I have tried to search IMDB but do you know how many hits "Aliens" and "sci-fi" get ? :)
It´s not the classic series "U.F.O", I have ruled that one out myself.
If you need any more info please let me know. Could anyone also tell me where to buy this series in its entirety then I would be forever grateful.

Sounds like the conspiracy sci-fi show Dark Skies from 1996:

The series presents the idea that 20th century history as people know it is a lie. It depicts aliens having been among humans since the late 1940s, with a government cover-up concealing their existence from the public. As the series progresses, viewers follow John Loengard and Kim Sayers through the 1960s as they attempt to foil the plots of the alien "Hive". The Hive is an alien race that planned to invade Earth through a manipulation of historical events and famous figures, including most notably the assassination of President John F. Kennedy. In addition, the pair must stay one step ahead of Majestic 12, a covert government agency that has mixed motives. 

John (Eric Close) starts out as a Majestic 12 agent. Kim is his girlfriend and I'm pretty sure the aliens kidnap her at some point. Here's a trailer [SLIGHTLY GRAPHIC]:



You can find the complete series on Amazon (like here and here).
